# How to add objects to tree branches?

Tags: modeling, mesh

Im modelling a tree and I would like to add an object (sphere, see below) to the end of each branch of my tree. Im currently doing it manually but Im pretty sure that isn't the best way.

Does anyone know an easier way to do it?

Thanks

P.S. I would prefer to not use Sapling Tree add-on because I need to fine tweak the tree by hand.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Set the tips as a vertex group and apply a particle system which would be the leaf ball. tweak the randomness to make something that seems natural.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know where to set my vertex group as a source of particles? Cant seem to find it...